# understanding sorting an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble understanding the sorting that occurs in the last if statement block. Can someone please explain how it works or useful resources i could refer to? I posted a screenshot of the source code for reference. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWGik.png)

```
           if (currentIndex != i) {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = temp;
            arr[currentIndex] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = currentIndex;}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  Include the code in your question as well as details explaining the problem.

Comment: That sort is not going to do what you want.  You need a temporary variable to store a `double` as you swap the two values in `arr`.  Also, may I suggest that calling two arrays `array` and `arr` throws away a golden opportunity to use variable names that actually describe what's being stored?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need that `if` statement. `currentIndex` (which starts at `i`) defines what the current position of the maximum value we haven seen is. Of course, if the value that you initially chose (at position `i`) is the maximum value, then in the inner for loop (with `j`) would never change the value of `currentMax` and `currentIndex`. The `if` statement is just saying if the value that is already at `i` is the maximum value (meaning `currentIndex` never changes), then there is no point in swapping the value at `i` and `currentIndex` because they are the same position.

For example, take the following values:

```
10, 8, 3, 2, 6
```

Let's say we have already placed `10` into the correct position (as the greatest value, that would be the first value you find and put into the correct position). Then, the for loop with `i` would move to the next value (position **1**). So you set `currentMax` and `currentIndex` to the following:

```
currentMax = 8
currentIndex = 1
```

At which point you move onto the inner for loop with `j`. Starting at `i + 1` (or **2** in this case), you check all of the values to the right of your `currentIndex` to see if there's any value greater than `currentMax`. Since you don't see any, then `currentMax` doesn't change (so it stays at **8**), which also means `currentIndex` doesn't change (stays at **1**).

So we come to the `if` statement. We know that:

```
currentIndex = 1
i = 1
```

Since the `currentIndex` and `i` equal each other, there is no point in swapping the values because they are the same values. Of course, you don't really need that if statement since swapping a value with itself doesn't really affect anything.